# Sacar número y porcentaje en una gráfica de highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estoy haciendo una gráfica combinada.
Estoy atorado en cómo representar la línea en 2 valores, tanto en número como en porcentaje. No entiendo si la misma Highcharts realiza los cálculos o debo añadir una serie o nodo de data adicional para poder representar. Sería una regla de 3 para sacar el porcentaje.
La formula sería

> 100 - ( (llamadas atendidas * 100) / llamadas recibidas  );

No entiendo dónde poner o enviar un arreglo ya con esa información, pero cómo renderizo ambos valores, abandono en valor y en porcentaje

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Inbound'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'junio']
    },
    labels: {

    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Recibidas',
        data: [7128,5067,5816,6005,6569,7260]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Atendidas',
        data: [5664,4820,5456,5401,5846,5503]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Abandonadas',
        data: [1463,159,360,603,722,1757]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Abandono',
        data: [1463,159,360,603,722,1757],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },
        tooltip: {
           pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br/>'
        },

    }, ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: En que parte de la gráfica debes mostrar los valores que indicas? Regularmente yo lo he hecho con formatter: function()

Comment: Exactamente en la línea de abandono, cada punto tiene un valor Abandono: 1 000(0.0%) es aquí donde quiero poner el porcentaje

Comment: De acuerdo a la documentacion de highcharts, el porcentaje solo esta disponible en las series `stacked` y en los `pie`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: En la [documentación de Highcharts](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#.percentage) se indica que `percentage` es para puntos en un stacked series o pie. Pero estás usando una línea y parece que no funciona para eso (por ejemplo, si pones "pie" como tipo sí se verán los porcentajes, pero no como tu quieres).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes la opcion de manipular los datos, puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var recibidas = [7128,5067,5816,6005,6569,7260];
var atendidas = [5664,4820,5456,5401,5846,5503];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Inbound'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'junio']
    },
    labels: {

    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Recibidas',
        data: recibidas
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Atendidas',
        data: atendidas
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Llamadas Abandonadas',
        data: [1463,159,360,603,722,1757]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Abandono',
        data: [1463,159,360,603,722,1757],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }, ],
    tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
             if (this.series.name == 'Abandono') {
               var index = this.series.data.indexOf( this.point );
               var percentage = 100 - (atendidas[index] * 100) / recibidas[index];
               return this.series.name +  '<b>' + this.point.y + '</b><br>' + percentage.toFixed(2) + '%'
             } else {
               return this.series.name +  '<b>' + this.point.y + '</b>'
             }
           }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Está casi perfecto, sólo si me apoyas a quitarle el mismo formatter a las barraS y dejarlo en la línea, te deposito hoy mismo :P

Comment: Ya edite, por ese simple `if` te voy a cobrar doble

Comment: Gracias, ya te mandé un camión de cervezas.